# How can I simplify filtering for elements in an F# array that don't exist in another array?

Tags: f#

I have 2 F# arrays to compare. For one of the functions I must find all the elements in array 1 that don't have an element in array 2 with the same key field.

I managed to get something that works but I must admit I get a little cross eyed trying to read it now. I feel for the developer who will have to modify this later on.

Is there a simpler and more readable way to express this in the `findWorkItemToClose` function?

```
/// Gets the ICCM call number given a work item reference id. The reference id may have a dash number suffix on the call number.
let getIccmCallNumberFromReference (referenceId:string) =
    if referenceId.Contains("-") then
        referenceId.Substring(0, referenceId.IndexOf("-"))
    else
        referenceId

/// Gets the TFS work items where the ReferenceId no longer exists in the set of open Iccm calls.
let findWorkItemsToClose (allWorkItems:WorkItem[]) (iccmCalls:Iccm.IccmCall[]) =
    let openStates = Set.ofList ["New"; "Approved"; "Commited"]
    let openWorkItems = allWorkItems |> Array.filter (fun wi -> Set.contains wi.State openStates)
    openWorkItems
    |> Array.filter(fun wi -> 
        not (iccmCalls 
                |> Array.exists (fun ic -> 
                    ic.CallNumber = getIccmCallNumberFromReference (wi.Fields.["ReferenceId"].Value.ToString()))))
```

**UPDATE**: Posting alternate version 1 (from suggestions in the answer) and alternate 2 using an array comprehension.

```
/// ALT 1: Gets the TFS work items where the ReferenceId no longer exists in the set of open Iccm calls.
let findWorkItemsToClose1 (allWorkItems : WorkItem []) (iccmCalls : Iccm.IccmCall []) =
  let callNumbers = iccmCalls |> Array.map (fun ic -> ic.CallNumber) |> Set.ofArray
  let openStates = Set.ofList ["New"; "Approved"; "Commited"]
  let openWorkItems = allWorkItems |> Array.filter (fun wi -> Set.contains wi.State openStates)

  openWorkItems
  |> Seq.groupBy (fun wi -> getIccmCallNumberFromReference(wi.Fields.["ReferenceId"].Value.ToString()))
  |> Seq.filter (fun (callNumber, _) -> not (Set.contains callNumber callNumbers))
  |> Seq.collect snd
  |> Seq.toArray

/// ALT 2: Gets the TFS work items where the ReferenceId no longer exists in the set of open Iccm calls.
let findWorkItemsToClose2 (allWorkItems : WorkItem []) (iccmCalls : Iccm.IccmCall []) =
    let iccmCallNumbers = iccmCalls |> Array.map (fun ic -> ic.CallNumber) |> Set.ofArray
    let openStates = Set.ofList ["New"; "Approved"; "Commited"]
    let openWorkItems = allWorkItems |> Array.filter (fun wi -> Set.contains wi.State openStates)

    [|
        for workItem in openWorkItems do
            let callNumberOnWorkItem = getIccmCallNumberFromReference(workItem.Fields.["ReferenceId"].Value.ToString())
            if not (Set.contains callNumberOnWorkItem iccmCallNumbers) then
                yield workItem
    |]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not 100% sure it's what you want but if I'm correct you can :

1. Get the distinct CallNumbers (if they aren't already distinct otherwise just use your original array ; not sure about making that a set or an array [perf concern maybe])
2. Group your work items by the CallNumber inside it's ReferenceID ; getting you a `seq<string * seq<WorkItem>>`
3. Filter to only keep keys (the callnumber) that aren't in Array/Set defined in step 1.
4. Finally "join" back the work items and make it an array

I used Seq to avoid to creating arrays at each step (memory concern) and also rewrited the other function in what seems (to me) a simpler way.

```
let getIccmCallNumberFromReference (referenceId : string) =
  match referenceId.IndexOf "-" with
    -1    -> referenceId
  |  0    -> "" // to be consistent with the original function
  | index -> referenceId.[.. index - 1]

let findWorkItemsToClose (allWorkItems : WorkItem []) (iccmCalls : Iccm.IccmCall []) =
   // see comments if you choose to use a set instead of an array
  let callNumbers = iccmCalls |> Array.distinctBy (fun ic -> ic.CallNumber) // |> Set.ofArray

  allWorkItems
  |> Seq.groupBy (fun wi -> getIccmCallNumberFromReference(wi.Fields.["ReferenceId"].Value.ToString()))
  |> Seq.filter (fun (callNumber, _) -> not (Array.contains callNumber callNumbers)) // replace Array.contains by Set.contains
  |> Seq.collect snd
  |> Seq.toArray
```

Comment: Those are very nice improvements! The iccmCalls.CallNumber is unique so I just convert it to Set. I really like the use of Set.contains which makes the exists filter much easier to grasp. The new version of getIccmCallNumberFromReference works perfectly. Indexing into the string with .[.. index -1] is new to me. More concise than Substring.